# If we compress a large amount of charge into a very small region, what will happen? Will it become something similar to that of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, electric-fields, charge

Just a hypothetical question...

Let's say that there is **some external force** that's **able** to **bring** and **sustain** large amounts of charges in a very small region, will it exhibit properties that could be analogous to a black hole?

Assume that this **external force** can overcome the strong electrostatic interactions.

Comment: Depends on what attributes from the black hole you mean. In the GR situation you have an extreme curvature of spacetime. That causes all reference points to converge on a single point(loosely speaking). In the QED analogy your curvature in the EM field cannot surpass "the speed of light". Also, there is also a scale for which the the QED running coupling diverges(way above planck scale).

Comment: Considering the extreme curvature of spacetime caused due to this scenario, will the resultant black hole, in any way, differ from the black hole caused by extreme gravitational effects?

Comment: Note, that in general relativity external forces do contribute to spacetime curvature, so the  answer may depend on the nature of this external force.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a hydrogenic atom/ion, that is, a nucleus of charge $Z$ with only one electron. For the Klein-Gordon equation you must have $Z \lt \alpha/2$ and for the Dirac equation $Z\lt\alpha$ for the atom to have a ground state solution. If $Z$ is larger there is no solution. This holds if the nucleus is modeled as a point charge. For a finite nucleus the limit is higher. Whether this behavior is similar to that of a black hole is a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Quarks do have EM charge. If you bring enough into a small enough region of space, you will get a neutron (where the quarks are in confinement) or a quark star (free quarks).

> Some massive stars collapse to form neutron stars at the end of their life cycle, as has been both observed and explained theoretically. Under the extreme temperatures and pressures inside neutron stars, the neutrons are normally kept apart by a degeneracy pressure, stabilizing the star and hindering further gravitational collapse. However, it is analyzed that under even more extreme temperature and pressure, the degeneracy pressure of the neutrons is overcome, and the neutrons are forced to merge and dissolve into their constituent quarks, creating an ultra-dense phase of quark matter based on densely packed quarks. In this state, a new equilibrium is supposed to emerge, as a new degeneracy pressure between the quarks, as well as repulsive electromagnetic forces, will occur and hinder gravitational collapse.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star

Though, neither of these have the properties of a black hole (in terms of forming an EH).

To have a black hole you need gravitational collapse.